# C# fixed point to floating point

Tags: c#, floating-point, fixed, truetype

I'm trying to get true type font glyph outlines using sample code from [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/getglyphoutline.html?diff=y).

There are some small errors in the code, including the fact that it only considers the whole part of the fixed point values that represent point positions of the glyphs.

There seem to be lots of examples of converting floating point values to fixed, but not vice-versa.
How can I convert the whole FIXED value to a floating point value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed Point to Floating Point and Backwards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574487/fixed-point-to-floating-point-and-backwards)

Comment: do you mean like from `int` to `double` .. isn't that already done by implicit conversion..

Comment: @Hogan Not really since that only tells if it's safe and not how to do it in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's a

```
public struct FIXED
{
    public short fract;
    public short value;
}
```

that you want to convert to floating point. Such [fixed-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_numbering_formats#Fixed-point_numbers) can be converted like this

```
var fix = new FIXED { value = 42, fract = 16384 };
double floating = fix.value + (double)fix.fract / 65536;
```

I divide by `65536` because a `short` is 16 bits (2^16). It's actually kind of strange that's it a `short` and not a `ushort` since a fraction can't be negative.

Comment: Had already tried this; it's either not correct for this type or there's some crazy stuff going on in the fonts that I'm not taking into account.

Comment: Further reading indicates you're correct. There must be some crazy hinting shizzle going on in the fonts I'm using.